# Repeating sections in s a file with replace() python

Tags: python, templates, output

I have a template file, and when I find specific strings I replace them with certain values.

Input file

```
The following are the names of the company
The name is [NAME]
--

Company number for each name

( [NAME]

 Company number [NUMBER]

)


Incorporated
```

I want the output to look like this

```
The following are the names of the company
The name is Julie
The name is Stan
The name is Nick
--

Company number for each name

( Julie
 Company number 00
)

( Stan
 Company number 02
)

( Nick
 Company number 03
)

Incorporated
```

Here is my python code

```
input = open("input.txt")
output = open("output.txt","w")
name=['Julie', 'Stan', 'Nick']
number=['00','02','03']    

i = 0

for row in input:
   if "[NAME]" in row:
      row=row.replace("[NAME]",name[i])
      i+=1
   output.write(row)

input.close()
output.close()
```

I was thinking of detecting an area to repeat values, like a for loop.

```
[FOR]
  ...
[/FOR]
```

Where if I detect a [FOR], then go through and populate the area with the amount of [NAME] needed.  This is how I want to go through the Company number of each employee in it's own section. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly adjust the approach to this problem.  I would separate the template in to larger sections, construct each section based on your variable number of inputs, and then replace/insert those sections into the template.

```
  # input.txt

  The following are the names of the company
  [names_section]
  --

  Company number for each name

  [company_numbers_section]

  Incorporated


  #script.py

  names = ['Julie', 'Stan', 'Nick']
  numbers = ['00','02','03']    

  names_section = ''

  for name in names:
     names_section += 'The name is {}.\n'.format(name)

  company_numbers_section = ''

  for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
     company_numbers_section += '( {}\n'.format(name)
     company_numbers_section += ' Company number {}\n'.format(number)
     company_numbers_section += ')\n\n'


  template = open('input.txt', 'r').read()

  template = template.replace('[names_section]', names_section)
  template = template.replace('[company_numbers_section]', company_numbers_section)

  with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
     output.write(template)
```

Comment: I like this solution. However, I want the user to be able to create the template and decide on how the output is formatted.